# One 'public static' statement for a group of class members?

Tags: php, class

I've got nearly 100 public static variables in a class that goes like this:

```
namespace Stats;
class City {
    public static $name =               '';
    public static $mayor =          '';
    public static $population =         '';
    public static $gdp =                '';

    /* more like these */

}
```

Is there any way to group all these variables into one 'public static' statement so it looks like this?

```
namespace Stats;
class City {
    public static {
        $name =                 '';
        $mayor =                '';
        $population =           '';
        $gdp =                  '';
    }
}
```

Comment: u should use an array instead

Comment: Why on Earth are those fields static?

Comment: as @bad_boy suggested, you may use an array.. or an object maybe. Why static anyway?

Comment: This must be the most testable code on earth

Comment: array sucks, that's why JSON is born

Comment: Wut? How exactly is JSON > array?

Comment: @kavoir.com what is the point is comparing JSON and ARRAY in the code you have posted??

Comment: two legs bad, four legs good...

Comment: I'm trying to come up with a consistent way to store config variables for multiple levels, the platform, the app, the theme, etc. I don't think arrays are a good idea here.

Comment: Really? whereas having hundred public static variables make sense ? Come on...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class City {

    public static $name       = '',
                  $mayor      = '',
                  $population = '',
                  ...;

}
```

This *does* sound like a terrible idea though. The properties by their name sure sound like they're instance properties and have no business being static. Be aware that public static properties are essentially nothing more than global variables. Empty strings as default values also aren't a very usual thing to do; use `null` instead.